# How can i get a tableview to count a week 1 day per row (ex: monday jun 10th = row 1.. tuesday june 11th row 2) using swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How can i get a tableview to count a week 1 day per row (ex: monday jun 10th = row 1.. tuesday june 11th row 2) timestamped on a label using swift in xcode 7? i know how to get the current time but i need it to count 7 days and leave the date until the week starts over.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please include some code of what you have tried in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar`. For example if you're looking to get the dates of the current week starting Monday, you can say something like:

```
func datesForCurrentWeek() -> [NSDate]
{
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    let components = calendar.components([.Weekday], fromDate: date)
    let weekday = components.weekday == 1 ? 8 : components.weekday

    var weekArray = [NSDate]()

    for i in 2 ... 8
    {
        let components = NSDateComponents()
        components.day = i - weekday
        weekArray.append(calendar.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: date, options: [])!)
    }
    return weekArray
}
```

Here you just determine what the current day of the week is, and then create an array that includes it and the six other days that encompass that week. You also need to shift it so Monday is the start of the week, as Sunday is the default.

You can then create a property like "dateStringArray" to hold your dates as strings. For example:

```
let datesArray = datesForCurrentWeek()
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .FullStyle
self.dateStringArray = datesArray.map{
    dateFormatter.stringFromDate($0)
}
```

Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can populate your cells:

```
cell.textLabel.text = self.dateStringArray[indexPath.row]
```

For more information on `NSDateComponents` see [here](http://nshipster.com/nsdatecomponents/) and [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDateComponents)